# Launch my app by clicking URL from WhatsApp

Tags: android, url, android-sharing

I have an app for daily news, knowledge sharing, etc. In this, by clicking the share button we can share a particular news item with others in WhatsApp/Facebook/Twitter etc. If the other person clicks this URL, different web browsers are displayed to open the post. But I want my app to be listed in this list if the user has installed my app otherwise open in a web browser. How to do this in android?

Comment: Similar question was posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30054843/7026117

Comment: This is called Deep-Link or App link. Check out this documentation. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch the Android App using deep linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772086/launch-the-android-app-using-deep-linking)

Comment: thank you all for the answers. I can now share it via WhatsApp and open my app from there. But by sharing it to Facebook/Twitter, I can not open my app? any reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in **AndroidManifest.xml** so it will always open your app separately.

```
 <!-- Deep & App Link -->
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="google.in" />
     <data android:scheme="https" android:host="google.in" />
 </intent-filter>
```